# NodeJS can't get error message from jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, jwt

this is my first time using jwt with npm jsonwebtoken, here's my code:

```
//create a token for user
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, email:user.email }, 'secret', { issuer:'Dio', expiresIn: '1h' })

//get the token from req.header
const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, decode)=>{
    try{
        console.log(decode);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

when the authentication failed, it's always print out "***undefined***".

Then I try the other ways:

```
jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, decode)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(decode);
    }
})
```

it works fine when the token is correct, otherwise I get the error message like:

```
JsonWebTokenError: invalid token
```

or

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ȗ in JSON at position 0
```

but I hope that I can get the information show in the npm document such as:

```
err = {
    name: 'TokenExpiredError',
    message: 'jwt expired',
    expiredAt: 1408621000
  }
```

Comment: you can include the token as well...might be easier to assist with it...

Comment: Thx, I had edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code block 1**

Try catch doesn't work that way. There is no error so it will never go in the catch statement. Callbacks are just functions. Here it accepts two arguments and there are no uncaught or caught exceptions or errors in that.

So it will always print `console.log(decode);` and it will be **undefined** as you have an invalid or expired token.

**Code block 2**

It should print the error. You have invalid syntax(`{` missing after if) here so that is the reason for the exception.

```
jwt.verify(olderToken, "lololol", (err, decode) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(decode);
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I miss the left parenthesis, my problem still exists

Comment: What is your question then? question was why it's undefined or exception is there? sorry if I am missing something here.

Comment: I have edited my question again, I hope this help you to understand my problem.

Comment: I think I get the problem, I'm really foolish. sorry for make you confused.